# mistakenly created new branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I renamed my local branch, then renamed remote branch, and then instead of just `git push` I mistakenly created new remote branch by `git push origin my-new-branch`. How can I link my local branch with right remote branch instead of created?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the changes you made to the old branch & remove the branch you created by mistake. To do that, merge the newly created branch into your original branch.

```
git checkout original-branch-name
git merge newly-created-branch-name
```

And then just remove the unnecessary remote branch you created by mistake.

```
git push origin --delete newly-created-branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to mess around with the remote branch, just reset the upstream branch:

```
git checkout original-branch
git branch --set-upsteam-to origin/original-branch
```

Just pushing a branch does not set up tracking, so you might not need to do this.